# Htaccess RewriteRule mark query , replace ?==&

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

- Htaccess code

  ```
  RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?(.*)?$ ./?query=/search/$1&$2 [L]
  ```
- Eg I want to link the
  http://localost.com/search/key/?get=get
- Then it got a 
  http://localost.com/?query=/search/key&get=get
- But why not get it right?
- I replace the `? =` Other characters are ok ...
- Who helps you with pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.+?)/?$ /?query=/search/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- RewriteRule only matches request URI without query string
- QSA flag is used to append existing query string

Comment: Actual absolute voi, you really giới.
That have been resolved, but 1 problems that web sitile me run the whole trang example
http://localhost/search/b/page-2/?get=get that it again not work to be!

Comment: Thankssssssssssssss youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu